# How to show SystemTray Message when Frame is not iconified

Tags: java, system-tray, trayicon

Is there a way to display a TrayIcon Message

```
tray.displayMessage("Warning", "Array index out of range", TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
```

when a JFrame is not iconified?

MadProgrammer brought me the idea. I had the code

```
if(e.getNewState()==NORMAL){
    tray.remove(trayIcon);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

so the TrayIcon was removed when i tried to display a message.

Comment: Yes, just do it. The `TrayIcon` is not associated with any other windows, in fact, you don't even need to have any windows at all to make it work. The question I have is, have you tried it? If so, what happened? If it didn't work as expected, what was the code you used to try it?

Comment: Thank you, your answer brought the idea! I had the code to remove the TrayIcon when maximized so it cant work xD Thanks a lot!